# "from unexpected" when createQuery

Tags: java, intellij-idea, hql

I get a error when I createQuery:

> 'from' unexpected

[image]

My code is below:

```
    @Override
    public Admin findByAdmin(Admin admin) {

        return (Admin) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().
                createQuery("from Admin where admin_name=? and pwd=?").
                setParameter(0, admin.getAdminName()).
                setParameter(1, admin.getAdminPwd()).
                uniqueResult();

    }
```

Comment: Do you need `SELECT {fields} FROM Admin . . .`?

Comment: @HanletEscaño No, I `select *`.

Comment: The query syntax looks OK, this might be a bug in the IDE's parsing of HQL.  If you compile and run does the code actually work?

Comment: @JimGarrison It can run, but get a 404, I don't know if is caused by the issue. I think have possibility is the IDE's parsing of HQL bug too.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I'm new to this but had the same error. What fixed things was adding the Hibernate facet under Project Structure - Facets.

Answer (score 34):

### To fix this error in intelliJ idea

> `Your Project (Right-Click) ---> Framework support` `:` *check mark* on **"Hibernate"**

> Press **OK**.

Comment: This added a hibernate facet, I already had the JPA facet but seems this wasn't enough.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't find **Hibernate** in your **Project Structure** settings (`File --> Project Structure... --> Facets`) then go to `File --> Settings --> Plugins` and type **Hibernate** in search field and verify if plugin is added to Intellij. After that you will find it under **Facets** in your project settings and add support.

In my case this was what helped me.